# Static casting a pointer to a pointer C++

Tags: c++, pointers, static-cast

Would someone help me understand why the second static cast `auto cpp = static_cast<Base **>(bpp);` fails. The first static cast, nicely checks to ensure that that Der is related to Base. Why does the second static_cast cause the compiler to throw the following error. Thanks!

`main.cpp:35:17: error: invalid ‘static_cast’ from type ‘Der**’ to type ‘Base**’`

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

class Base
{
};

class Der : public Base 
{
};

int main()
{
 
    Base a;
    Der b;
    
    Base * ap = &a;
    Der * bp = &b;
    
    auto cp = static_cast<Base *>(bp);
    
    Base ** app = &ap;
    Der ** bpp = &bp;

    auto cpp = reinterpret_cast<Base **>(bpp);
    //auto cpp = static_cast<Base **>(bpp); // Why does the cause an error?

    printf("Hello World");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This would allow assigning an `OtherDerived*` to the target of that pointer, breaking type safety.

Comment: Not sure what specifically in the standard prevents this but I suspect that in specific situations, this type of conversion could cause confusing behavior or be wrong. Converting from derived to base class can require a pointer adjustment to account for the offset of a secondary base class within the class layout, but if you're pointing to that address, the value of that address can't be magically changed through a `static_cast`. I assume it was simpler to disallow that type of conversion entirely than to selectively allow conversions that don't require a pointer adjustment.

Comment: While a `Der*` can be converted to a `Base*` (because inheritance is an "is a" relationship, `Der` *is a* `Base`), `Der**` is a totally different type from `Base**`. Once you add more indirection the "is a" relationship no longer applies.